# Keras Adam minimize function: no gradients provided

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, minimization

I need to optimize a function with Adam Optimizer (no Neural Network involved). I made a dummy example to understand how it works, using the `minimize` function but seems like I'm not getting it. It's a simple function that returns the dot product between two arrays (as tf variables). Code bellow:

```
    np.random.seed(1)
    phi = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.random.rand(32))
    theta = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.random.rand(32))

    loss = lambda : tf.Variable(np.dot(phi, theta))

    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
    niter = 5
    for _ in range(niter):
        optimizer.minimize(loss, [phi,theta] )
        print(phi[:5].numpy(),theta[:5].numpy())
```

I'm getting the following error in return:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['Variable:0', 'Variable:0'],).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because TensorFlow does not know how to compute the gradients of non-TF methods (`np.dot()`). You can use `tf.tensordot()` or `tf.matmul()`.

Comment: And also why are you assigning the result of dot to another tf.Variable?

Comment: @Frightera it works, thank you. It was very basic mistake after all, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. `tf.tensordot()` did. the trick.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy because one error was leading to the other. Without the referring assignment the error was that `float64` doesn't have an _id, since I was using a numpy operation and returning a regular float number.